# How do I TFTP download from base directory mounted to a drive partition

Tags: rhel, mount, tftp

I am working with an external SATA drive, and would like to be able to have remote hosts be able to TFTP download files from it. However, when I set my TFTP base directory to my mount location, I get the following error on the client when I attempt to download:

`curl: (68) TFTP: File Not Found`

As a sanity check, I stopped TFTP on the server, unmounted the drive, and created a file in the root filesystem with the same name, in same directory that I had mounted the drive to previously. I then restarted TFTP, tried to download again on the client, and had no issues pulling down the file. Are there any considerations I may have missed in regards to trying to TFTP from the drive?

For what it's worth, the TFTP server is running on a VirtualBox Red Hat 7.3 VM, and my client is the VM host (Windows 10). I'm using cURL from a Cygwin session to do the TFTP downloads

Comment: If you don't know what the tftp server is doing, just [`strace`](https://strace.io/) it (or (x)inetd) while your curl command executes. You'll see where it's looking for the file. inotifywait could be enough if you have an idea where this could be.

Comment: To solve the problem, one needs to know the tftp server configuration as well as the curl command you issue. I suggest you add those details to the question. Furthermore, doesn't the tftp server generate log messages? Can you make them verbose?

Comment: Well, I've got part of the situation figured out. I have a udev rule that is supposed to run a script that creates the directory, mounts the drive there, then starts the TFTP server. Turns out udev mounted the drive in a private filesystem namespace, so I'm thinking TFTP was started on a directory that was actually in the local filesystem, and mounting after that . Got the mounting working, now I'm getting a -71 due to an SELinux policy, but progress has been made